# How do I change the bootstrap hamburger icon for the nav bar in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble changing the icon in the Navbar for bootstrap 4. My current html is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="images/logo.svg" width="60px" style="margin-right: 10px;" alt="logo">
    <span class="logo-text logo-text-small">Brand</span>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
 }
```

The image is in `images/hamburger-icon.svg`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Inspect the element with your dev tools. Is your `background-image` the last one that's applied to the element? If not, then you need to increase the specifity. Is it the last one but image is not showing? Check in the network tab which path the browser want's to load exactly and if the image is available under this path.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dear please use this css it will work:


 .navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
       background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
       background-size: 100%;
       background-position: center center;
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggler-icon {
       background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
       background-size: 100%;
       background-position: center center;
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       display: flex;

    }

    .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
       background-image: url("images/hamburger-icon.svg");
       background-size: 100%;
       background-position: center center;
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       display: flex;
     }
```